# Error In Updating Image using $_FILES

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, image-uploading, image-upload

I have written the following code to update Images that are stored in Files. The code is working perfectly when I am using it to Upload image, but when I am using it to Update Images, it is giving me 'Invalid file' error message. It is getting problem in the first 'if' statement and directly going to its else statement message 'Invalid File'. Kindly check it and guide me.

Thanks

```
<?php

var_dump($_REQUEST);
session_start();
error_reporting(E_PARSE);
if (isset ($_SESSION['username']) )
{

    //echo "<div id='nav'";
    echo "<ul><hr>
     <li><a href='insert_product.php' >Add Product |    </a></li>   
     <li><a href='add_category.php'> Add Category </a></li> 
      <li><a href='sub_categories.php'> Add Sub-Category </a></li>
     <li><a href = 'view_products.php'  >View All Products</a>  </li>
     <li><a href = 'all_categories.php'  >View All Categories</a>  </li>
      <li><a href='view_all_sub_categories.php'>View All Sub Categories</a></li>
     </ul></hr>";

    include 'connect.php';


    $category_id=   $_GET['category_id'];

    $query=         "select * from category where category_id= $category_id";
    $query_run=     mysql_query($query);
    $fetch=         mysql_fetch_array($query_run);
    $name=          $fetch['name'];


echo "  
            <form action='update_category.php?category_id=$category_id' method='POST' >
            <table border=1>

            <tr><td>
                Category Name:</td><td><input type='text'  name='category' value='$name'  />
            </td></tr>

            <tr><td>    
                Image1:</td><td> <input type='file' name= 'image' >
            </td></tr> 

            <tr><td>            
                <input type='submit' value='Update'  />

            </td></tr>

            </form> </table>    ";

            echo "<form action='delete_category.php?category_id=$category_id' method='POST'>
                <input type='submit' value='Delete'>
                </form>
            ";

            if (isset($_POST['category']) )
            {

            $category_name =         $_POST['category'];

             $query_update="UPDATE  category SET  name =  '$category_name'
                                WHERE  category_id =$category_id ";


                        if (mysql_query($query_update))
                        {
                            echo "Records updated";

                            }
                            else
                            {

                                echo mysql_error();
                                }




                    /*-------------------
                        IMAGE QUERY 
                    --------------------*/
                    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
                    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["image"]["name"]));

                        if ((($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/gif")
                        || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
                        || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
                        || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
                        || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
                        || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/png"))
                        //&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000)
                        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
                        {
                          if ($_FILES["image"]["error"] > 0)
                            {
                            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["image"]["error"] . "<br>";
                            }
                          else
                            {
                                echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["image"]["name"] . "<br>";
                                echo "Type: " . $_FILES["image"]["type"] . "<br>";
                                echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["image"]["size"] / 200000) . " kB<br>";




                                    $image_name=        $_FILES["image"]["name"];  
                                    $random_name=       rand().$_FILES["image"]["name"];

                                    $path=              move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],
                                                                "upload/categories/" . $random_name);


                                     $folder="upload/categories/" .$random_name;        

                                        echo "Stored in:    "."upload/categories/". $random_name;

                                    echo    $sql=   "update category_images set name='$image_name' ,
                                                location='$folder' where category_id= $category_id      ";  


                                        $result = mysql_query($sql);
                                        if ($result)
                                        {

                                         echo "successfull"; 
                                         } 
                                         else {
                                                echo mysql_error();
                                                }


                            }

                        }

                    else
                      {
                      echo "Invalid file". $_FILES["image"]["error"];
                      }


                        /*-----------------
                        IMAGE QUERY END
                        ------------------*/                    

            }

            /*
                echo    $sql=   "update category_images set name='$image_name' ,
                            location='$folder' where category_id= $category_id      ";  
                */          
}

else 
{
    echo "You Must need to Log in to Visit this Page";

    }


?>
```

Comment: Prove that $_POST['category'] is actually set, var_dump() it.

Comment: Output of var_dump($_POST['category']) = string(2) "12"

Comment: It is updating the Name of the category, but not updating the Image of the category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Just changed this

```
 <form action='update_category.php?category_id=$category_id' method='POST' >
```

to

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action='update_category.php?category_id=$category_id' method='POST' >
```

and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this code:

```
<?php 
 include 'connect.php';
 extract($_POST);
 $category_id=   $_GET['category_id'];
 if(!empty($_FILES['image']['name']))
  {
   $filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];
   $filesize = $_FILES['image']['size'];
   $ext = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filename, "."), 1));
   $image_size = ($filesize / 1024);
   if($filename != '')
    {
     if($ext == 'jpg' or $ext == 'jpeg' or $ext == 'gif' or $ext == 'png')
 {  
     $max_qry = mysql_query("select max(category_id) category_id from category");
     $max_row = mysql_fetch_array($max_qry);
     $id=$max_row['category_id']+1;
     $fname= $id.str_replace(" ","_",$filename);
     $image_path = "img/".$fname;
     $up_path = "img/".$fname;
     copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$image_path);
     chmod($image_path,0777);
    }       
  }
 $query=mysql_query("UPDATE category SET img='$fname' WHERE category_id='$category_id'");
 if($query)
  {
   echo "Updated";  
  }
}
}

?>
```

Comment: I have just copy & paste your code in my file, but it is still not updating the image, and if I add echo "Invalid File" in the else statement then it prints the 'Invalid file' message.